# Is there anyway to use switchCompat without resetting while running app in java, Android?

Tags: java, android, switchcompat

I am having Stopwatch app.
I have Switchcompat for different backgrounds on the main layout.
When I tap the switch while running the time, it is reset to 00:00:00.

Is there any way to use the switch without resetting the timer?

Here are some parts of the code.

***MainActivity***

```
    SwitchCompat switchCompat;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        switchCompat = findViewById(R.id.switchCompat);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("night", 0);
        Boolean booleanValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("NightMode", false);
        if (booleanValue) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            switchCompat.setChecked(true);
        }

        switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    switchCompat.setChecked(true);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("NightMode", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("NightMode", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [saving instance state pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-activity-state-using-save-instance-state) - store time value and re-store when `Activity` recreates

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("SwitchText", switchCompat.getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switchCompat = findViewById(R.id.switchCompat);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) { // is null on first start
        String switchText = savedInstanceState.getString("SwitchText");
        // may be null when no value stored under given key
        if (switchText != null) switchCompat.setText(switchText);
    }
    ...
```

`Activity` gets recreated/restared because in `onCheckedChanged` you are calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` - this is forcing `Activity` to restart and apply new theme, and you have to write some additional code for saving previous state